# How can I get to know variables defined in the methods of a jimple file correspond to what variables in a java class file?

Tags: java, class, variables, soot

Soot transforms a java class file into a jimple file with local variables renamed. Now I want to know the scheme based on which Soot does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by code in the Soot repository [here](https://github.com/Sable/soot/blob/master/src/soot/javaToJimple/LocalGenerator.java), it appears to use the original local names while using names prefixed with `$` and a single-character reflecting the type for the generated ones.